# Whats the simpler way to mock call to classes from the `java.time` classes in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalatest, mockito-scala

In javascript for example the jest library has a facility to kind of travel through time to test time dependent code, [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimemstorun), or in ruby on rails you have facilities to mock time like [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html). I'm looking for something similar in Scala that could allow me to mock calls to `LocalDateTime.now` from `java.time` for example, but I haven't found anything like the tools I just mention or how to mock `LocalDateTime.now`

Comment: @GaëlJ you didn't point to any particular answer

Comment: By the way, I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. When capturing the current moment, you need the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. That means calling `now` on `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: You shouldn't be mocking those classes. If you want to control the values generated, you should use a `Clock` and inject one which you control during your tests, and use `LocalDateTime.now(clock)` instead of `LocalDateTime.now()`.

Comment: I end up passing lambda to obtain the time that I mocked on the tests